# Difference between "as" or "as is"

Tags: clauses, ellipsis

What is the difference between saying:

> 1. "as clearly stated in the agreement..."
> 2. "as is clearly stated in the agreement.."

Comment: More context is needed.

Comment: Seconding @user3169's request: Why don't you provide the source of your confusion? That way we'll be able to address your issue specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is very subtle.

The first would be used like this:

> You agreed to pay $100, as clearly stated in the agreement.

Or the second:

> As is clearly stated in the agreement: "You will pay $100"

Note that the "is" version has an implied subject "it" "as it is".

This is passive voice, the subject "it" is being "stated".

The version with no "is" however doesn't imply a subject, which means this dependant clause need to get its subject from another clause. In this case the entire independent clause at the beginning becomes the subject of the dependant clause.

Note however, that you could still use the "is" in the first one - it's just not necessary. However removing it from the second example would be technically wrong - though I doubt anyone would notice.